# Как запустить скрипт в фоновом режиме?

Tags: node.js

Не совсем понимаю, как точнее сформулировать вопрос, поэтому в гугле пока мало информации нашел. Буду рад, если кто-то подскажет, как правильно называется это явление)

Суть в том, что, допустим, есть сервис, который для каждого пользователя постоянно парсит заголовки новостей с выбранных пользователем сайтов. С точки зрения и фронта, и бэка в целом всё ясно. Но как реализовать вот этого самого "бота", который бы работал постоянно?

Comment: crontab
запуск по расписанию..

Answer (score 0):

На сервере запускаете скрипт `nohup node script_name.js &` и будет крутиться в фоне.

Если по умному, то лучше запускать под чем-нибудь вроде [Supervisord'а](http://supervisord.org/).

Конкретно для ноды ещё есть [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

Comment: Я использую pm2, он тоже подойдет? Могли бы вы уточнить, как именно это должно работать? В данный момент понятно, что пользователь регистрируется, заходит в личный кабинет и указывает список интересующих сайтов, затем он нажимает "старт" и какая функция должна быть выполнена в этот момент? Что из себя должен представлять этот скрипт - чистый js или отдельное приложение? Что должно произойти на сервере - для каждого пользователя должен запуститься свой экземпляр скрипта? В общем вопросов много, если вы дадите ссылку на что-то релевантное, буду очень признателен.

Comment: @Андрей вполне.

Comment: Немного дополнил свой комментарий. Пока дополнял, вы уже ответили)

Comment: @Андрей ваш комментарий тянет на отдельный вопрос =/ Если надумаете задать, пинганите меня потом тут, подумаю над ответом.